# Changing innerHTMl while keeping CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I have a paragraph inside a div:

HTML:

`<div id="header"><p>Header</p></div>`

CSS:

```
#header p {
color: darkgray;
font-size: 15px;
```

When a button is clicked, the innerHTML Changes:

Javascript:

```
var header = document.getElementById('header')
header.innerHTML = "Changed"
```

However, the after innerHTML is changed, the text returns to its original attributes. I would like the text to keep its color (darkgray) and font size (15px).

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7skLhz99/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're subsequently removing the nested `p` element (which is what the CSS is being applied to).

You could select the first child node and then change the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/772ohht0/)

```
var header = document.getElementById('header');
header.childNodes[0].textContent = "Changed";
```

The benefit to accessing the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property is that it will either select a child element or a text node. This means that the text will be changed even if the `#header` element doesn't contain a descendant `p` element.

In other words, it would replace the text in `<div id="header"><p>Header</p></div>` and `<div id="header">Header</div>`.